# Fusion layer not getting plotted

Tags: google-maps

I have a Google Map with 3 layers on it.

- a) Region
- b) State
- c) County

They appear when you zoom in the map.

Here is the code - https://jsfiddle.net/djz43usz/

```
//county level
         if(zoom_level >= 7) {
          clearRegion();
          marker_point = country_center;
          id = c_id;
          area_type="COUNTY";
          mark_center(); 
           layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            query: {
              select: '\'geometry\'',
              from: '1fio1qgy5HkinUDKqYvREIlSoBaHjl2RBe3DLJa38'
            },
            styles: [{
              polygonOptions: {
                fillColor: '#000000',
                fillOpacity: 0.001
              }
            },{
                where: "'GEO_ID2' IN ("+draw_str.toString()+")",
                polygonOptions: {
                  fillOpacity: 0.3
                }
              }]

          });
          layer.setMap(map);

          }
        });
```

Region and state works well. But for county, fusion layer doesn't work. Is there anyway I can resolve it?

This is how it looks right now:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I look at the javascript console, I see: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 413 ()`.  The issue is that the `draw_str` string is too long (it is 17555 characters long).  In this line:

```
where: "'GEO_ID2' IN ("+draw_str.toString()+")",
polygonOptions: {
  fillOpacity: 0.3
}
```

You need to reduce the size of that query string (to fit the URL maximum of 2048).

- related question: [Limit to query length in Fusion Tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199378/limit-to-query-length-in-fusion-tables)

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/djz43usz/1/) (with layer showing)

Comment: I have dynamic views, i.e. on 1 page, it can be draw_str having 50 geocodes, whereas on another page it can be 1500, so I cannot really reduce the size. Is there a way to overcome this limitation and/or way to filter it on page?

Comment: Same answer I gave the last time you asked this question: [Google Maps Fusion Table layer not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238551/google-maps-fusion-table-layer-not-working)